# Ember resource templates in one folder

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, url-routing

I have these routes in my Ember.js app:

**router.js**

```
EmberRails.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('stories', function () {
    this.resource('story', {path: '/:story_id'});
  });
});
```

And this is what my Ember Inspector outputs in the **routes** tab:

[image: Application Routes]

Now, in the "Template" column (second from right), Ember tells me where it expects the templates should be for the different `Story` resources. As you can see, it wants certain templates directly in the `/templates` directory, and some in `/templates/stories`. I can see no reason for this and personally I find it confusing and ridiculous.

Is there any way in Ember to use a Rails-style convention, like this:

Show ('story') - `/templates/stories/show`
Index - `/templates/stories/index`
Edit - `/templates/stories/edit`
etc..

Comment: If you want to nest inside stories you need to use 'this.route'. Change this.resource('story', {path: '/:story_id'}); with this.route('story', {path: '/:story_id'});

Comment: "Error while processing route: stories.index" "Assertion Failed: You specified the templateName stories for <EmberRails.StoriesView:ember405>, but it did not exist."
@blessenm

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ember CLI and it's [pods feature](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-pods) to do this. It was [recommended by the Ember core team](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15) that all Ember applications move to Ember CLI as soon as possible.

If you aren't or don't want to use Ember CLI, you can overwrite the regular `Ember.DefaultResolver` methods to change the resolver's functionality. There is a [short example in the Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.DefaultResolver.html).

Comment: How does Ember CLI co-operate with [ember-rails](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails)? I've been playing around with an Ember CLI test app, but I decided to test ember-rails out in its own app at first. For example, if you use both, would there be clashes in functionality or conventions? And would you use `ember serve` or `rails s`, etc.?

Comment: Rails and Ember CLI work really well together. Rails wouldn't serve any assets, it just acts as an API. Ember CLI builds the app, serves the assets and you can deploy easily on a Node server from someone like Heroku or AWS. Utilizing a Node server for your frontend will allow you to take advantage of things like Ember Fastboot as Node functionalities become more central to the advantages of an Ember stack. You have two applications so you'd use `rails s` and `ember s` in separate terminal tabs.